# Bind Collection of objects to ComboBox in DataGrid SilverLight

Tags: .net, xaml, silverlight, combobox, datagrid

I have a problem, I'm tring to bind a Collection of objects to ComboBox (cell in datagrid).

I have the ComboBox in my grid, but it is empty with no data (the Collection is not empty):

```
<sdk:DataGrid Name="CdnsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" RowHeight="40" Margin="0,20,30,20"  RowEditEnded="LinesDataGrid_RowEditEnded">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Welcome Message">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ComboBox Name="VoiceMessagesComboBox" SelectedIndex="3" Width="250"  ItemsSource="{Binding VMCollection}" SelectionChanged="OnVMSelectionChanged">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="200" Height="46">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>      
</Grid>
```

The Collection item has: ID,Path,Description:

I'm trying to show the description of the combobox item in the grid, and on "save" click, get the ID of the item (by row)

Any idea, how to solve it?
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Since your ComboBox is in a DataGrid it is in a Context of that DataGrid. Looks like you are accessing a collection on the ViewModel, so you'll need to specify the source.

One option is to specify your View Model as a Resource on your User Control and specify it as a source to your ComboBox ItemSource.

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:My.App.ViewModels"


<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="myViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<sdk:DataGrid Name="CdnsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" RowHeight="40" Margin="0,20,30,20"  RowEditEnded="LinesDataGrid_RowEditEnded">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Welcome Message">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ComboBox Name="VoiceMessagesComboBox" SelectedIndex="3" Width="250"  ItemsSource="{Binding VMCollection,  Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}" SelectionChanged="OnVMSelectionChanged">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="200" Height="46">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

If you are setting your DataContext through Code Behind, this approach will not work.  In that case you will need to do Element Binding.

Comment: Thanks. I posted the Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox has current collection item ('row') as data context, but collection is located in VM. You can specify relative source for your binding and point it to parent DataGrid (whos data context is VM):

```
<ComboBox Name="VoiceMessagesComboBox" SelectedIndex="3" Width="250"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.VMCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid}}" 
          SelectionChanged="OnVMSelectionChanged">
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted the Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Finally this is how I did it, and it works:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Name="cbxFuelType" SelectionChanged="cbxFuelType_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{StaticResource VMCollection}">                                                       
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="200" Height="46">
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Description,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
```

Now, I need to show The Description, by ID, When the DataGrid is loaded.
Any idea?